# How popular is GRAILS BeanBuilder for replacing xml based spring configuration?

Tags: java, spring, grails, jakarta-ee

Interested to know how many are using [BeanBuilder](http://grails.org/Spring+Bean+Builder) in production as a replacement to XML based config for Spring 3.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How would you go about doing that? It's been proposed that the Grails bean builder be added to Spring in a future release but that hasn't happened yet.

Comment: I am not sure and that is why I was asking. While I was going through the comments posted in this article, someone mentioned this as an alternative to the XML config and I found this interesting. http://blog.springsource.com/2007/05/14/annotation-driven-dependency-injection-in-spring-21/